# WP8 - Bind ProgressBar visibility

Tags: binding, windows-phone-8, progress-bar, visibility

I have a simple thing to code, i checked other questions but couldn't it yet.

I have an application which loads some data from an xml file retrieved from the web, and then displays it inside a longlistselector.

I did it, it works, now i would like to add an indeterminate progressbar which stays active until I finished the data loading.

I enclosed the progressbar in a stackpanel, before my longlistselector, and i bound its visibility to the function ProgressBarVisibility (see code below).

```
        <phone:PivotItem Header="Status">
            <StackPanel>
            <ProgressBar Value ="0" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="{Binding ProgressBarVisibility}"/>
            <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotOne}">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- lots of code here -->
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
            </StackPanel>
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

In the MainViewModel.cs , that's how i wrote the thing.

```
    using System.Windows;


    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.PivotOne = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        this.PivotTwo = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        this.PivotThree = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A collection for ItemViewModel objects.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> PivotOne { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> PivotTwo { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> PivotThree { get; private set; }

    private string _detailPageTitle = "Default";
    /// <summary>
    /// DetailPageTitle ritorna il titolo della pagina di dettaglio. Viene settato nella funzione che carica la pagina secondaria
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string DetailPageTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return _detailPageTitle;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _detailPageTitle)
            {
                _detailPageTitle = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DetailPageTitle");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }


    private Visibility _progressBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    public Visibility ProgressBarVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _progressBarVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _progressBarVisibility)
            {
                _progressBarVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ProgressBarVisibility");
            }
        }
    }


    private Visibility _progressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

    public Visibility ProgressBarVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _progressBarVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _progressBarVisibility)
            {
                _progressBarVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ProgressBarVisibility");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public void LoadData()
    {
        //progressbar is visible, data not loaded
        this.IsDataLoaded = false;
        ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

        // Load Static and dynamic data -- populate the different pivots
        LoadStaticData();
        LoadXMLFile();

        // data loaded, progressbar collapsed
        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

So i included system.windows library, and used the visibility class.
Anyway, i cannot get the progressbar to disappear when the loading is done, it keeps going.

Any suggestion? where am i doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Solution: loaddata is executed on the app activation, so the content is not even rendered at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MainViewModel must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to signal to the View that one of the properties has changed. In addition, when you change the `ProgressBarVisibility` property, it should fire the `PropertyChanged` event.

There are a number of [MVVM](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) [frameworks](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) that come with some implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, but you could easily implement [something simple](http://jesseliberty.com/2012/06/28/c-5making-inotifypropertychanged-easier/) yourself.

Comment: hi, i actually had that implemented in my model. I used it but i cannot get it to work anyway. I edited the question correctly now.

Comment: @Mik1893, Just to make sure that we're not missing something obvious, can you post your `NotifyPropertyChanged` implementation and the MainViewModel class declaration (are you in fact implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?)

Comment: @Mik1893, another thing to check is whether you get any Binding errors in the output window when you debug your app

Comment: i add it to the main question

Comment: @Mik1893, I can't reproduce your error given the code you posted (in my case, the progress bar is collapsed); there's something else going on. As a side note, the way you implemented your `LoadStaticData` seems to be a synchronous operation on the UI thread, which means that either your UI would be non-responsive. Or, if your `LoadData` is called from the constructor of MainPage.cs, then the data would be loaded before the page is even rendered, meaning that your progress bar is not even going to be rendered.

Comment: You won, correct answer: infact it doesn't get rendered. I found the correct place where to execute the loading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to report the changed made to the view:

Change

```
public Visibility ProgressBarVisibility { get; set; }
```

by

```
private Visibility _progressBarVisibility;
public Visibility ProgressBarVisibility
{
    get { return _progressBarVisibility;}
    set { _progressBarVisibility = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ProgressBarVisibility");}
}
```

Make sure you implement INotifyPropertyChanged or a base ViewModel that implement it (MVVMLigth : ViewModelBase).

Comment: the best would be too replace the Visibilit type and changing it to a bool and thenusing a BooleanToVisibilityConverter.
http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/useful-calue-converters

Comment: hi, i actually had that implemented in my model. I used it but i cannot get it to work anyway. I edited the question correctly now.